# Removing close button and back button

Tags: java, javascript, winapi

Can someone tell me how can I disable the browser's close button and back button. i.e user can not see the browser's close button or back button or can not click on the close button or back button of the browser. If user clicks nothing should happen or it should be completly hidden from user.

Solution can be in java or javascript or win32 apis..

Comment: just create a new browser with no close and back button.. but i doubt anyone will use your browser...

Comment: Are you serious? and can you please tell me which product/company you are working on? I need to suggest my IT department to blacklist all of  your products. :P

Comment: Sounds like a technique for one of those "less than reputable sites" that doesn't want you to ever leave.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use case? Would a full-screen browser (F11) be helpful? And if the close and back buttons are not available, how would the user leave the site?

Comment: I would assume that this is for some kind of "kiosk" application, in which case you may not want users to close the window. In this case, some browsers (Chrome springs to mind) have a "Kiosk" mode, which may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

We use this technique in-house for opening a browser window on top of all other apps so the user can use in-house hosted forms/webapps etc. Please remember to offer a close button.

NB: This **only** works for IE:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <script for="window" event="onload">
      window.open('main.jsp',
      'Your Name',
      'width=800,height=600,resizable=0,status=0,toolbar=0');
      <!-- Stops user from being able to press BackSpace -->
      window.opener = window.top;
      window.open('', '_self', '');
      window.close();
  </script>
</html>
```